# Sqlalchemy 1.4 & preventing attribute refresh accessing attribute on detached instance in flask

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

We're having and odd issue, and an intermittent one. For better or for worse, we're working with an app that uses a SQLAlchemy object under the hood stuffed into `g`. The model has a few columns, and a couple relationships defined as `lazy="joined"`.

The issue that we're having, intermittently, is that sometimes when we access `g.current_user.username` (`g.current_user` is set during setup of the request context, the value of which is an instance of our `User` model, that *has* data), we get a `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Instance <User at 0x7ff9f7059fa0> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed` exception

This issue happens randomly - it's not consistent.

Why does this happen at all, given that we treat the object as read-only, and we're accessing a top-level attr that already has data? Why is it insistent on attribute refresh despite it being detached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably happens when you reference the user attributes after the session was committed after changes were made causing the `current_user` to be marked as expired and the session was then closed/removed.  Sometimes that can happen when accessing it inside a template (depending on your framework and session configuration)  You can turn that off but then you will probably have a second set of issues.

[SEE: committing](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_basics.html#committing)

Specifically:

> Finally, all objects within the Session are expired as the transaction
> is closed out. This is so that when the instances are next accessed,
> either through attribute access or by them being present in the result
> of a SELECT, they receive the most recent state. This behavior may be
> controlled by the Session.expire_on_commit flag, which may be set to
> False when this behavior is undesirable.

So seems like these are some common options:

1. turn off `expire_on_commit` (probably not a good idea)
2. extract the user data you need before committing, ie. store a limited version of the current user, ie. `g.current_user_info = current_user.get_info()` (explicit but requires updating that info manually mid-request if you change it)
3. move the access to the `current_user` inside the session's transaction (maybe not possible for your app)
4. expunge the `current_user` object from the session when you first make it (functional but kind of confusing because it is implicit that the user is stale and reading the code it might not be obvious and people will try to mix it in with session bound objects or reference stale relationships on it)

Comment: Hey Ian, appreciate the thorough reply! We tried 1 as a diagnostic step and it did indeed cause all kinds of issues. 2 is a longer-term (and in our view, right) solution - for now, time permits band-aids and nothing more. We settled on 4 actually. Basically when we set `g.current_user`, the object we set is `session.expunge(user_object)`, which indeed seems to resolve the immediate issue. Not a great solution, I agree, but it does resolve the "issue"